# How to add a file in a matlab default search path

Tags: matlab

I want to add a file say `abc.m` in matlab default search path without modifying its path.

So I put the file in one of the folders of my default search path. But still matlab doesn't recognizes when I type the file name on the terminal. Any suggestions.

Here is the folder in which I put my file `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\toolbox\local`

Here are the contents of `abc.m`

```
 restoredefaultpath;
 clear all;
 clc;
```

I am not looking for answers like edit `startup.m` and use `addpath` to add the file path .

Comment: how sure are you that you've put it in one of the default folders ?

you can add folders to the path directly from the GUI, "preferences" iirc

Comment: @vish I do not want to modify the search path. And yes I am sure that I have put the file in one of default folders , I have added its name in the question

Comment: look for another file in that folder and try to call it, if you can, it sounds like there's a matter of reindexing, but i thought matlab did that every startup

Comment: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\toolbox\local` should already be on your default path, what does `which abc` return?

Comment: I got my error , I hadn't restarted the matlab instance. Thanks to @vish . Should I remove the question ?

Comment: only remove the question if you think no one will run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my error.

I forgot to restart the matlab instance so that it could index the files in its default search path